# How to get a UITableView with "Select All" and "Deselect All" buttons

Tags: mono, uikit, xamarin.ios, uitableview

I want to tableview accessory button like selectall or deselectall.
cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
I want to a button example :"select all"
When user touch this button everycell's accessory should checkmark.
Or I want "Reset" button. if user touch this button every checkmark disappear and Cell's accesory shoul none.

Comment: Can you be more descriptive ? can't understand your question.

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand your question. Can you edit it to provide more details ? in particular the what's the link between the buttons and UITableViewCellAccessory. The later is documented here: http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITableViewCellAccessoryNone

Answer (score 5):

As you have likely found out using UITableView is a bit complicated. However there's a wonderful library available for MonoTouch called [MonoTouch.Dialog](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog) that makes things a lot easier.

The following sample code is using MonoTouch.Dialog to answer your question (as much as I understand it, let me know if my answer does not match what you wanted).

```
    UIBarButtonItem [] selection_buttons;

    void Process (IList<Element> list, bool value)
    {
        foreach (Element e in list) {
            CheckboxElement cb = e as CheckboxElement;
            if (cb == null)
                continue;
            cb.Value = value;
            cb.GetImmediateRootElement ().Reload (cb, UITableViewRowAnimation.None);
        }
    }

    void Test ()
    {
        Section s = new Section ("Select items");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            s.Add (new CheckboxElement (i.ToString ()));
        var root = new RootElement (String.Empty);
        root.Add (s);

        var dv = new DialogViewController (root, true);

        // keep buttons in a field, not a local variable, to ensure it won't be GC'ed away
        if (selection_buttons == null) {
            selection_buttons = new UIBarButtonItem [] { 
                new UIBarButtonItem ("Deselect All", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, delegate {
                    Process (s.Elements, false);
                }),
                new UIBarButtonItem ("Select All", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, delegate {
                    Process (s.Elements, true);
                })
            };
        }

        dv.NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItems (selection_buttons, true);
        NavigationController.PushViewController (dv, true);             
    }
```

Have fun with MonoTouch (and MonoTouch.Dialog)!

Comment: Btw: Is the new static table stuff of SDK 5 bound in Monotouch or do you want people to use Monotouch.Dialog?

Comment: @Krumelur it should be there - anything missing is a bug. We seek to provide choices, including giving all of iOS power **and** easier API when possible (and it's more than possible wrt UITableView ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can checkout [this demo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableMultiSelect/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011189-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) from developer.apple.com. Hope it help you.